# windows 8 tabbar on left corner ,will microsoft approve

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

i am going to make application on windows 8 ,an app that has tab bar menu on left side. will my app get rejected if it get messy with the left side bar

will Microsoft allow placing app bar menu on left and right side of screen vertically that will share space with left side bar or charm bar .

what are developer guide lines for user interactive tab bar menu

Comment: I don't know if you can get an official answer just from documentation, but try looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It won't be rejected. But as far as UX is concern you should not do like this. As it will be mix up with charm bar i.e. left side vertical appbar will conflict with program pane and right side vertical app bar will conflict with charm bar.

You can use [Windows App Certificate Kit to test store certification process.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx)

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) has such appbar.